# Writing a dictionary to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am unable to write a dictionary to file using `json.dump` due to having Hebrew letters and the file just contains trash in English letters.

```
import codecs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = dict()
    k['tony ta'] = 4
    k['tt '] = 5
    l = list(k)
    with codecs.open('text.txt', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
        for i in range (0, len(l)):
            f.write('\n'+(l[i]) + ' ' + str(k[l[i]]))
```

Using codecs I am able to write it correctly and obtain the result I want. For this demo I'm using `open`. Is there a more convenient way to do this ?

> text.txt
>   
> tony ta 4
>   
> tt  5

Any better way rather than having to turn my dictionary to list and then access the dictionary to find the value ?

Answer (score 1):

So instead of converting the dictionary to a list, I converted it into a string and then did some string operation. I am not sure if you will consider this a "better" or a "more convenient" way.

```
import codecs
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = dict()
    k['tony ta'] = 4
    k['tt '] = 5
    with codecs.open('text.txt', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
        f.write(re.sub(r"[{}:']",'',str(k).replace(', ','\n')))
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use :

```
with codecs.open('text.txt', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
    for key in k:
        f.write("%s %s\n", key, str(k[key]))
```